# Liquibase generateChangeLog doesn't have tablespace information (Oracle)

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase 3.5.3 and generating the changelogs for an existing Oracle schema.

Following is the create table generated by liquibase generatechangelog . It doesn't include the tablespace name (our tables are in different tablespaces so the information is important)

```
<createTable remarks="test table" schemaName="APP_SCHEMA" tableName="TEST_TABLE">
```

Is it expected behavior or I can do some liquibase settings to get tablespace names in the generated changelogs?

Comment: What database engine are you using this with?

Comment: The database is Oracle.

Comment: Liquibase itself does not support this. Datical has implemented extensions to Liquibase that do capture this information. (I work for Datical).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the liquibase option "--includeTablespace=true".

```
./liquibase --includeSchema=true --includeTablespace=true generateChangeLog
```